# Spring Boot - Repository bean could not be found - SQL Server/JPA/API

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the below error even though such a bean does exist and *is in the same package as the Application and Controller

> Field profilesRepository in com.test.ProfilesController required a bean of type 'com.test.ProfilesRepository' that could not be found.

What could be causing this?

My file structure:
src
main
java
com.test
TestApplication.java (class)
Profiles (class)
ProfilesController (class)
ProfilesRepository (interface)

Profiles.java:

```
package com.test;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Profiles")
public class Profiles {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int id;
    @Column(name = "Username")
    public String username;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String name;
    @Column(name = "EmailAddress")
    public String emailAddress;
    @Column(name = "HomeAddress")
    public String homeAddress;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getHomeAddress() {
        return homeAddress;
    }
    public void setHomeAddress(String homeAddress) {
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    }

}
```

ProfilesController.java:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ProfilesController {

    @Autowired
    public ProfilesRepository profilesRepository;

    @GetMapping("/getAllProfiles")
    public List<Profiles> getAllProfiles() {
        return profilesRepository.findAll();
    }
    @GetMapping("/helloWorld")
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }


}
```

ProfilesRepository.java:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ProfilesRepository extends CrudRepository<Profiles, Integer> {
    List<Profiles> findAll();
}
```

TestApplication.java:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.test"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test"})
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Test</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-15T21:21:47.035-05:00 ERROR 32878 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

***************************

Description:

Field profilesRepository in com.test.ProfilesController required a bean of type 'com.test.ProfilesRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
\- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.Group3.GeekText.ProfilesRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: `ProfilesRepository` is an interface - where's the implementation class?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Spring creates an implementation in response to the annotation.

Comment: Remove the `javax.persistence-api` as 1 it is the wrong one and 2 it already comes with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. Unrelated but to improve your code, remove the `@Repository` from the repository, the `findAll` method is already provided (remove it as well). On your application class remove the annotations and only leave an empty `@SpringBootApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating my imports from

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

to

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
```